# Removing part of a column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to select both an entire column, and then just part of the column, but can't seem to make a `trim function` work. Not sure if this is even the correct function.

My Starting Data, which I still want, is like this:

```
JOB_CODE
02-7740-00
02-7741-01
02-7790-10
02-7821-05
```

I want an additional column that just gives me the last 2 digits of that string, so it would look like this:

```
JOB_CODE     Cost_Center
02-7740-00    00
02-7741-01    01
02-7790-10    10
02-7821-05    05
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: what did you write when you tried to select?

Comment: yet another example why you shouldn't combine different data into a single column.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [RIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx)

```
select JOB_CODE,RIGHT(JOB_CODE,2) as Cost_Center from table
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18520)</kbd>